# how to enable any page view error in nop commerce? This is a generic for all errors in nop mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Whomever is the person managing this, please understand this is a generic problem and I have not solved it. If someone can tell me how to let the page errors show up just as they do normally when no in MVC nop, please let me know. This is a generic question, I repeat. There is no specific error, its just any error. Whomever is voting me down because of that has no comprehension of the issue. This could be a simple answer like set the web.config on this or do this particular thing in nop to show page errors. That's all I'm asking. Jesus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in the nop mvc release notes. It seems this was a known issue and the creator himself of nop finally added the ability to see page errors. His latest release just addressed this issue. Now I have to figure out how to upgrade.

http://www.nopcommerce.com/releasenotes.aspx

See the "bugs" section. This is justification for my posts that were deleted prior on this very issue. EVERYONE was experiencing this issue using Nop MVC so how was I wrong on this topic? Who is downgrading me on this topic? This site needs QA on its QA.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open web.config file
2. Find out the following line `<customErrors defaultRedirect="errorpage.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">`
3. Replace it with `<customErrors defaultRedirect="errorpage.htm" mode="Off">`